# Align items vertical and horizontally in fixed height div without using flex property

Tags: html, css

How to align the `thank_pge_center` class vertically and horizontally within the fixed height div.

Without using `flex` property

```css
.cr_eve_cont {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 1px rgba(231,231,231,1);
}
.thank_eve_cont_inner{
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 450px;
}
.thank_pge_center{
    text-align: center;
}
.thank_pge_center p i{
    color: #00C95F;
    border: 2px solid #00c95f;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.thank_pge_center h1{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2795CA;
}
.thank_pge_center p{
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn_ok{
    text-align: center;
    background: #0097C7;
    color: #fff;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cr_eve_cont">
<div class="thank_eve_cont_inner">
<div class="thank_pge_center">
<p><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Thank you for your order</h1>
<p>Check your email for a booking confirmation.</p>
<p>We'll see you soon!</p>
<button class="btn_ok">ok</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answers below. For more on both checkout https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ and https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css to your code: (without using flex property)

```
.thank_pge_center{
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: translateY(-50%);
 }
```

```css
.cr_eve_cont {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 1px rgba(231,231,231,1);
}
.thank_eve_cont_inner{
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 450px;
}
.thank_pge_center{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
     top: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.thank_pge_center p i{
    color: #00C95F;
    border: 2px solid #00c95f;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.thank_pge_center h1{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2795CA;
}
.thank_pge_center p{
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn_ok{
    text-align: center;
    background: #0097C7;
    color: #fff;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cr_eve_cont">
<div class="thank_eve_cont_inner">
<div class="thank_pge_center">
<p><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Thank you for your order</h1>
<p>Check your email for a booking confirmation.</p>
<p>We'll see you soon!</p>
<button class="btn_ok">ok</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both answer were gud. i'm accepts this as answer because  it's related to my question. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**With using display table**

```
.thank_eve_cont_inner {
   display: table;  
}

.thank_pge_center {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
.cr_eve_cont {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 1px rgba(231,231,231,1);
}
.thank_eve_cont_inner{
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 450px;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.thank_pge_center{
    text-align: center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
.thank_pge_center p i{
    color: #00C95F;
    border: 2px solid #00c95f;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.thank_pge_center h1{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2795CA;
}
.thank_pge_center p{
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn_ok{
    text-align: center;
    background: #0097C7;
    color: #fff;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cr_eve_cont">
<div class="thank_eve_cont_inner">
<div class="thank_pge_center">
<p><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Thank you for your order</h1>
<p>Check your email for a booking confirmation.</p>
<p>We'll see you soon!</p>
<button class="btn_ok">ok</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**With flex box properyt in class(.thank_eve_cont_inner)**

```
  .thank_eve_cont_inner{
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
```

you can see also in snippet

```css
.cr_eve_cont {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-top: 32px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 1px 15px 1px 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px 1px rgba(231,231,231,1);
}
.thank_eve_cont_inner{
    border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 450px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.thank_pge_center{
    text-align: center;
}
.thank_pge_center p i{
    color: #00C95F;
    border: 2px solid #00c95f;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.thank_pge_center h1{
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2795CA;
}
.thank_pge_center p{
    color: #373737;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.btn_ok{
    text-align: center;
    background: #0097C7;
    color: #fff;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 8px 10px 8px 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cr_eve_cont">
<div class="thank_eve_cont_inner">
<div class="thank_pge_center">
<p><i class="fa fa-check fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
<h1>Thank you for your order</h1>
<p>Check your email for a booking confirmation.</p>
<p>We'll see you soon!</p>
<button class="btn_ok">ok</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible without using flex

Comment: Yes! Possible with absolute method and using table cell method

Comment: Also possible with position: relative; and keeping position:absolute; to the farthest..

Comment: I added also using table method